# Is there a limit to the size of a method that can be used in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, arrays, optimization, windows-phone-8, deployment

I have a working application for Windows Phone 7 that I am trying to recreate on Windows Phone 8. When I deploy the app to the attached device (Nokia 1020) I get the following error message: Deployment Optmization failed - “Method (s) exceeded the maximum size limit”. I'm using VS2013 Ultimate with the Windows Phone SDK 8.0 (10/30/2012) and the SDK 8.0 Update 3 Emulators package and the SDK 8.0 Update for Windows Phone 8.0.10322.

And everything works fine when I use a smaller dataset intended for debugging. The error occurs when I change from using 2 small arrays (50 integers and 50 strings) to the release versions which have 101,000 members. While these are obviously large and clearly responsible for the error they worked fine in WP7. However, in WP8 we get Deployment Optimization - great.

So does anyone know the maximum size limit for a method?

Comment: Wait wait wait... Can you explain what exactly do you mean by "101,000 members"? Can you show, like, the 10 first ones?

Comment: D: are you serious? 101k members of what? What are you doing?

Comment: It's the second time i read someone here in StackOverflow with more that 70k variables/members. I just ask... HOW? How many people involved? 500 people?

Comment: I'm creating a simple hash table of English words that gains the fastest performance as in-memory arrays. LocalDB is too slow and also has a 4MB limit, while the 2 arrays account for about 4.2MB (101,000 integers and strings). Oh and I should have used the word 'elements' instead of members in the question.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out in Windows Phone 8, there is a 256-KB limit on a method's Common Intermediate Language size as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206947%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). About halfway down the article it describes the CIL method size and states "App installation that succeeded under Windows Phone OS 7.1 may fail under Windows Phone 8. This should affect an extremely small number of apps."

Unfortunately that includes us, so we'll break it up into smaller parts and run it using the new asynchronous pattern.

Comment: Wow, I would never have thought that this kind of limitation would be documented. In any case, it would probably be better to find some kind of local storage and populate the hashtable during app startup